# How to create X11 window from GTK widget in FireBreath plugin?

Tags: linux, plugins, gtk, x11, firebreath

everyone!

I need to create browser plugin on FireBreath.

I'm trying to create child X11 window from GTK widget, but plugin crashes in firefox and works in chromium, but not displays...

I've created test desktop GTK application and went the same way: created child X11 window from GTK widget. And it works normal.

What can it be?

Thanks!